# Homomorphisms of abelian group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Working my way through Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter $0$", he mentions that the set of homomorphisms of abelian groups form an abelian group themselves. He doesn't go much into details at that point, but I started thinking about homomorphisms between such groups, specifically ones with common "target": $\text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(A,C) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(B,C)$.

Let $\alpha \in \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(A,C)$ and $\beta \in \text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(B,C)$. Initially I thought homomorphisms between the $\text{Hom}$s would correspond to homomorphisms $\varphi : A \rightarrow B$ such that:

[image: Diagram]

commutes, i.e. $\alpha = \beta \circ \varphi$. (Getting the inspiration from how he described slice categories)

I say "initially" since I also started thinking about the kernel of non-trivial $\varphi$ and it seems to me that it must always be trivial under this definition? (Too good to be true?)

My thinking was this: Letting $\beta$ be the homomorphism that sends everything to $0 \in C$; if $\varphi$ itself is not trivial, the only $\alpha$ that would make the diagram commute would be the one that sends everything to $0 \in C$ too.

What I'm not sure is if my misunderstanding comes from how I'm thinking about the homomorphims in terms of such diagrams or, if the previous view is correct, I'm just missing how a non-trivial $\alpha$ could commute with a trivial $\beta$. (Or it could be something completely different, of course.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Homomorphisms between $\mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(B,C)$ correspond to morphism going the *other* way, $f\colon B\to A$. You take $g\in\mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$, and map it to the morphism $g\circ f\colon B\to C$. On the other hand, morphism from $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ to $\mathrm{Hom}(A,C)$ correspond to morphisms $B\to C$ by composing on the right, instead of the left.

Comment: Given $\beta \in \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Ab}(B,C)$, one has a group homomorphism $\beta_* : \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Ab}(A,B) \to \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Ab}(A,C)$ that sends $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Ab}(A,B)$ to $\beta \circ \varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_\textsf{Ab}(A,C)$. Of course, if $\beta$ is trivial, $\beta^*$ is trivial as well, and then it sends non-trivial maps to trivial ones. Also, I think I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, I see, that makes sense! Part of the problem I was having was a function notation "issue" I think: It feels natural to write $f(g) = f \circ g$, but in this case it should be $f(g) = g \circ f$ as you explained, thanks!

Comment: @azif00 Sorry for the lack of clarity, it just reflected my own confusion I guess. I was just trying to see if my intuition of what such homomorphisms are was misguided or not.